# Confused about how to use JScover

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, testing

I need to check the test coverage in my Jscript application. I am using Qunit as unit test framework. I cannot make Jscover works properly. I haven't understood how should I use it, which command I should issue and which directories I have to specify in the path.

This is the structure of my file system :

```
JSON/ 
css/
html/
images/  
js/
test/
index.html
```

The code I want to test is in the js folder, while the qunit test are in the test folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can post this as a question at https://github.com/tntim96/JSCover/issues, but will try to answer here...

If you run the tests by pointing your browser at the 'index.html' file, and assuming that is in the directory 'c:/your-test-directory', you can run it via the server mode. For example:

```console
java -jar target/dist/JSCover.jar -ws --branch --document-root=c:/your-test-directory --report-dir=target --no-instrument=test --no-instrument=js/lib
```

I've added '--no-instrument=js/lib' to illustrate how to exclude 3rd party libraries, such as JQuery, from instrumentation.

Then point your browser at `http://localhost:8080/jscoverage.html?/index.html`

There is more information in the [manual](https://tntim96.github.io/JSCover/manual/manual.xml) too. Let me know how you go.